# Viewport Units not working in Cordova Mobile App

Tags: android, css, cordova, responsive-design, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying get responsive web design to my app so that it adapts to multiple screens. Hence I used viewport units(vw and vh) in my css for every thing from font-size to margin. But the cordova webview is not supporting the viewport units. I'm stuck here.

is there any way to workaround to get the vh and vw units to work on cordova webview?
or
is there any other way of getting responsive web design for my app so that I can release it across multiple screens(android).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I got js workaround it works fine in cordova app

code:

`var w=$(window).width()/100;
    var h=$(window).height()/100;
    function vw( val ) {
       return  w*val+'px';
    }
    function vh( val ) {
       return  h*val+'px';
    }
    $('.header p').css({
        fontSize: vw(4),
        marginTop: vh(2)
    });`

simple isn't it?

Comment: it solves the viewport issue, but how can you make UI components relocate themselves to fit in the different screen resolution? I'm having the similar issue now.

Comment: @Franva you can use media queries and some other js work-arounds(like detecting screen resolution)for getting UI components positioned in screen of different sizes(different screen resolutions).

Comment: hi, thx to your reply. but the website has already used bootstrap css. It works when I open the website directly in the mobile browser, but does not work after I used Cordova to wrap it up as a hybrid app and also run on Android mobile. Do you have any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

if u have tried:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

then try this:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: try this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />

Comment: its not working too what I initially used was <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/> and I'm testing this in my phone which is android 4.0 ICS. is there anything to do with the phone.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding some earlier versions of Android and IOS do not support viewport units
http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

I would use em instead of viewport units and I would add some media queries to html tag to manipulate on font-size. 
Unit 'em' is relative so if I change font-size on html it will scale font-size on its children